# Angular two way data binding on dynamically generated forms

Tags: angularjs

I have a three buttons that dynamically generate three slightly different forms. I'm having trouble creating two way data binding. The binding becomes the same for each form (for example if I add forms A, B and C and enter a comment in the comment field on form A, that comment will appear also on forms B and C). What I'm trying to do is that each form will have their own values, so if I enter a comment in form A this comment will only appear in that instance of form A. If I add another form A and enter a different comment there it shouldn't appear anywhere else but this second instance of form A.

I've created this plunker with my example/problem
http://plnkr.co/edit/6S4fdJ6OQuOqJPFmH9yx?p=preview

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MainFactory', function ($scope, MainFactory) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var frmCnt = 0;
    var dayCnt = 1;

    $scope.iti = MainFactory;

    var forms = [
      "frm1.html",
      "frm2.html",
      "frm3.html"
    ];

    ctrl.displayedForms = [];

    ctrl.addForm = function(formIndex) {
      ctrl.displayedForms.push(forms[formIndex]);
      console.log(ctrl.displayedForms.length);
    }

    ctrl.deleteNode = function(indx) {
      ctrl.displayedForms.splice(forms[indx], 1);
    }

    ctrl.isCollapsed = false;
  }]);
```

Factory:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('MainFactory', function (){
    return [];
  });
```

App

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute'])
```

Thank you for any help and/or suggestions.

Comment: `$scope.$watch` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding all the forms to the properties of the same object `iti`. Each `form` should be bound to its own View Model object. It's not clear why that object is bound to `myFactory` (which on its own right is confusing with how it's defined).

So, create a new object for each form (I'll stay away from `myFactory` for the purpose of this example):

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.formsVm = [];

  $scope.addForm = function(formIndex){
    $scope.formsVm.push(
      { 
        formVm: {}, // this will be your per-form ViewModel
        url: forms[formIndex]
      }
    );
  };

  // etc...
});
```

```
<div ng-repeat="form in formsVm" ng-init="iti = form.formVm">
  <ng-include src="form.url"></ng-include>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PjrorJCLgnoVMun0FkG7?p=preview)**